# how to correctly restore a mysqldump without access to a new one

Tags: mysql, ssh, phpmyadmin

I'm helping out a friend that did a very bad dump that can't be reverted or done the right way.

the command i suppose he used when trying to dump his site's database through ssh:

```
mysqldump -uroot -p database > BACKUP.bak
```

as a result his entire database seems to be encoded or something (i can only see weird characters)

I had to read a lot to figure out what was going on and have tried to transform the database back to UTF-8 so i can import it.

current path of the dump -->  `/tmp/backup.bak`

I tried importing the DB dump using this command (which i later read was also not the best way to do so):

```
mysql -u username -p database < dump_file
```

But the dump is never imported since it throws an "unknown character \X" (where X is one of the "gibberish" characters i mentioned above).

I tried to encode it to UTF8 as well both manually (notepad + save with different encoding) and through SSH when importing it but it still didn't work.

Is there a way to go around this issue?

Comment: By default, **mysqldump** writes information as SQL statements to the standard output. Redirecting to a file is a convenient way to be able to later import it back. But the file should still contain all the SQL statements and can be read with any text editor or via **less/more/cat** Linux utilities. Can you share a part of the file where you see the weird characters? Have you modified the file? If yes, what that on a Linux or Windows machine and with what utility?

Comment: First of all, thanks for the answer! the entire document is basically a huge mess of special characters. the backup was done using PUTTY on a windows machine and for some reason unknown to me the file was saved as .BAK instead of SQL (i believe my friend did it forllowing a guide that had that format). The database is a mariaDB dump and you can see a small part of it here: https://pastebin.com/HhN9T0Bs @Sergiu

Comment: There seems to be nothing on that pastebin link. Now, a mysqldump file on Linux/Unix even with extension .bak is still and ASCII text file so unless the file was opened on a Windows machine and saved, you should still have the good data in it. Before transferring it from Linux/Unix to Windows machine it would be good to change the extension from .bak to something like .sql or even better .txt. On Windows it should be opened with apps like Notepad/Notepad++ not Microsoft Word.

Comment: Interesting. i had opened it before (when i sent you the pastebin) but only now i can see something weird. please look at this: http://prntscr.com/v9du0e

Notice how it says "macintosh", i know for a fact it wasn't opened on a mac at all. 

Here's the correct Pastebin: https://pastebin.com/DqqhqQ2M